# What is the point of triple JCASE automotive fuses?

Tags: automotive, fuses

Some JCASE automotive fuses come three in one enclosure. What problem do they solve? What do they do that three individual fuses couldn't do?

[image]

{My pictures}

The BUSSMANN MPF [spec sheet](https://www.eaton.com/content/dam/eaton/products/electrical-circuit-protection/fuses/data-sheets/bus-ele-ds-10602-mpf.pdf) (PDF) says;

"Eaton Bussmann™ series multi-pole fuses (MPF) are cartridge fuses containing three fuse elements of the same or differing ampacities for protecting three circuits with a single design."

Comment: Please link to a data sheet for the part (I think you know the drill by now LOL). Also, what circuits are they in?

Comment: "what circuits are they in?" -- I don't know. I don't have the schematic diagram for my car.

Comment: Then get the wiring diagram and you will see what circuits or components are protected.

Comment: " get the wiring diagram and you will see what circuits or components are protected" That was not my question. That was Andy's question.

Answer (score 0):

You already provided the answer.

Quote: "Eaton Bussmann™ series multi-pole fuses (MPF) are cartridge fuses [!sic] protecting `three circuits` with `a single design`".

**(1)**

`Single design` in automotive means x1-Power-Point presentations in the planning-stage, x2-Meetings with x3-Companys in the design-stage and x4-Tests during the evualtion.

"Summarize" x1-xN and you get: `Cost`

You reduce this cost by having to do all these tasks only for a single component instead of three.

**(2)**

`Single design` in automotive means `single supply-chain`. You need x1 people to handle the chain, x2 things can go wrong in the logistics, x3 companys can go bankrupt and blow your chain, x4 legal requirements on the chain and maaaaaaaaaaaany more problems.

"Summarize" x1-xN and you get: `Cost`

You reduce this cost by having to do all these tasks only for a single component instead of three.

**(3)**

`Single design` in automotive means x1 parts can cause a recall, x2 parts can cause trouble due to lack of reliability, x3 parts need to be known by your contract maintenance infrastructur and maaaany more.

*I repeat my self:*

"Summarize" x1-xN and you get: `Cost`

You reduce this cost by having to do all these tasks only for a single component instead of three.

**It reduces cost by reducing complexity through combination. That is why it is used.**

You can of course argue over the points given. You can go back and forth and back again.

But: There are points.

So: Points can get problems.

**And: Problems cost money.**

Removing the points removes the problems and therefore saves you cost.

Comment: Add to that, if you blow one fuse you need to replace all 3 and the relatively obscure replacement part probably costs much more than 3 single, easy to source, standard ones, so more `profit`